# Looks like a have two accounts via Google OpenID

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, openid, stack-exchange-openid

This is me - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176052/pinal

Today I have some notifications for this account - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/2158/pinal

[image]

I tried to restore my access to 2158 account, but any different OpenID from OpenID for 176052 account just offer me to create a new account.

So looks like I need help to restore access for 2158 account or this notifications is a bug?